# How to customize Text(Justify,colors..) in TextView Comming from local sql Database in android?

Tags: android, database, text, textview, justify

I want to customize the text in `TextView` whose text is fetched from SQLite database. How I can justify the text, color some words and add a different stylein my andoid application.

How I can use this for exemple:
`<Font COLOR=red> My text </Font>` in database.

Thank You.

Comment: Use `Spannable` or `Html.fromhtml();`

Comment: you may use spaneable String

Comment: Thank you. can you show me an exemple ?